# Find infimum of set A: $A=\{\frac{m^4 +2n^2}{2m^2 -m^2n + n^2}: m, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Find infimum of set A:

$$A=\{\frac{m^4 +2n^2}{2m^2 -m^2n + n^2}: m, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

So, I know that supremum is in $\infty$ for $ \displaystyle  \lim_{m \to +\infty}$ and $n=1$.

I know that infimum $=\frac{3}{2}$ and is obtained when $n=1$, $m=1$, but I don't know how to actually calculate that. It seams that the expression is not monotonous, so I wouldn't seek try to express it using one variable. On the other hand, there are only 2 variables no it is unlikely that it is inequality of means

Comment: The infimum is not a positive number. Consider $n=3, m=4$.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, it should be $n^2$ in the nominator. I am so sorry.

Comment: If $m=n^2$, then it goes to $-\infty$

Comment: But I don't think that that's the right answer. I have drawn a graph in desmos and it looks like it is 1 for sure. Now I see that there is the case where it goes to $- \infty$ and I'm a bit confused. Maybe that's the answer.

Comment: How did you come up with that?

Answer (score 2):

if $n=3$ we obtain the sequence
$$\biggl{\{}\frac{m^4+18}{-m^2+9}\biggr{\}}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$$
and this diverges at $-\infty$ for $m\rightarrow  +\infty$

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, it should be $n^2$ in the nominator. I am so sorry.